# Can an Android application identify the test track within Google Play

Tags: android, google-play-services

Google Play supports various 'test tracks' to allow test builds to be distributed to different groups through the Google Play Store:

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Google Play uses the application version number to decide which apk should be delivered to the user from the set of test tracks that the user qualifies for.

Given that an apk can be promoted to different test tracks, is it possible to detect (within the Android application) which test track was used to deliver the apk? For example, is it possible to know (within the Android application) that the application was delivered through an alpha test track or a beta test track?

The motivation behind this question is to enable different sets of features through a server-side configuration based on the test track an application was delivered through.

It's possible to manage this through version numbers alone but knowing which test track an application was delivered through would make this process easier.

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Since it is not possible, maybe you are interested to understand more about the workflow of [Google Play APK's and Tracks](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/tracks). My insight could be, that they are limiting the identification of the track where the app to be release as a protection for any illegal imitation of the app itself. Let say for example, if a user will was aware that it was delivered from an "`alpha`" or "`beta`" track then it could be a big trouble to copy and make some enhancement for that app.